# How can I get Sublime to autocomplete the closing tag as I start typing it?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Let's say I type `<div></`. How can I get Sublime to fill in the rest (`div>`) automatically?

Answer (score 2):

you can type div without <> and then press TAB, what you will get is
      <.div> <./div>

alternatively, you can type first div with <> and then press ALT+. for the closing tag on the windows

Answer (score 0):

The Emmet plugin supports this pretty nicely: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime

Comment: On another machine I have, Sublime does this natively. I looked through my settings there and couldn't find it.

Comment: if you type the tag and then press [tab], does it do anything?

Comment: It just indents the current line with a tab character.

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete should be enabled by default for html, if its not you can set it under Preferences/File Settings

see [sublime docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html)

Comment: `auto_complete` just shows a menu of predictions as you type, it does not do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a missing key binding here. Add the following in your user key binding.
`Menu » Preferences » Key Bindings - User`

```
// HTML, XML close tag
{ "keys": ["/"], "command": "close_tag", "args": { "insert_slash": true }, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "(text.html, text.xml) - string - comment", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": ".*<$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "setting.auto_close_tags" }
    ]
}
```